# Update an image in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="change" value="Update Image!" />
</form>
```

and this action here :

```
if(isset($_POST['change']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $img = "photo_gallery/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $query = "UPDATE gallery SET image =\"{$img}\" WHERE id = $id";
    $up = mysql_query($query, $connection);

    if(!$up){
        echo die(mysql_error());
        echo "error,not updated!";
    }
}
```

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Any help for finding the error please!

Comment: Did you try:   $qury = "UPDATE gallery SET image ='{$img}' WHERE id = $id";

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Using $_POST values directly in SQL statements is bad.  Make sure you escape the value for id.

Comment: try echo $qury after $qury="..." and you will see what is the exact query that is sent to DB. Furthermore it is a bad practice to include posts directly in queries it is vulnerable to SQL injection. The simplest way is where you have id's you get from posts to cast to integers. I would do $id=$_POST['id']+0; it will return 0 even if s.o. put a text in the post/get

Comment: @venimus: Don't you come from Java ? Reminds me that I used to append `+""` to integer to cast them into string.

Comment: `die` does not return a string. And trying to do stuff after calling `die` is quite pointless. `die` kills your script with a message.

Comment: @Clement, nope (10 years in php) but it does the job perfectly. Don't think you could cast strings to integers in java this way (well not sure, I've never wrote in Java)

Comment: i did that and, i fined that id won't be post to the php code but why? i echo the id in form i still have the id but wont post!

Comment: @user743473 there is no <input name="id"> in the html you posted. So no $_POST['id'] in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the id value in your form.

As a side note: you are exposed to a SQL injection attack both via the id parameter, as well as the file parameter... And if you pass the id in the form you may allow to maliciously alter images that were not intended to update.

=== Below: edited by someone else. As a note: htmlentites will not guard against SQL injection (use mysql_real_escape), and md5 will guard against injection but not against file overwriting (if someone uploads a file with the same name it will clash). Moreover, if you pass the ID in the form, one can change it and alter an unintended image.  ===

Try to secure your code :

```
if(isset($_POST['change']))
{
    $id = htmlentities($_POST['id']);
    $img = "photo_gallery/" .md5($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $query = "UPDATE gallery SET image =\"{$img}\" WHERE id = $id";
    $up = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    if(!$up)
    {
        echo die(mysql_error());
        echo "error,not updated!";
    }
}
```

Comment: $id = htmlentities($_POST['id']); would trigger an error if id is a text! use $id=(int)$_POST['id']; or $id=$_POST['id']+0; Else you are right about missing the id into the post, it wasn't obvious before he updated his question. May be it is supposed to be $_GET['id']. Of course you should not have ID's 0 -> rule #1 in SQL

Comment: and anyway, htmlentities is not the right one to call: use mysql_real_escape instead

Comment: `htmlentities` is not the way to guard against SQL injection.

Comment: i solved the problem,i added this to the form :

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" /> 
and the php code like this:

if(isset($_POST['change']))
{
    $id=$_POST['id']+0;
    $img = "photo_gallery/" .($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $query = "UPDATE gallery SET image ='{$img}' WHERE id = $id";
    $up = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    if(!$up)
    {
        echo (mysql_error());
        echo "error,not updated!";
    }

}
** NOTE/** i had the hidden input for id but i didn't echo the value,i echoed id my problem was solved,

Comment: b.t.w. why i cannot update images with any image i want?! i just can update with some images cause they being upload but can't show them in web page,any one has any idia?

Comment: You only store filename of image, not actual image data. Call move_uploaded_file() to actually copy the file into a permanent file.